# Page is not loading on refresh when I pass data through link in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

When I pass data through link in reactJS, for the first time component is successfully loading. But on refreshing the page I am getting blank screen. I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone please help me on this.

```
      <Link
        data-automation-id={`${row.Id}`}
        to={{ pathname: `/xyz/${row.Id}`, state: row }}
        key={row.surveyId}
       >

       <Route path={`${baseRoute}${RoutePaths.page}`}
                component={Details}
       />
```

Comment: what is the error you see in browser console  ?

Comment: Could you provide a working example so we can better understand/debug the problem? Thanks